# SAPUI5 Bind Property Names with forward slash

Tags: sapui5

I have to bind a table using an uploaded excel sheet which consists of some size information as columns. 
And some of the sizes have forward slash "/" in the size names.

eg: S/4 , M/5, XL/6

So these sizes will be the **dynamic** columns of the binding table.
The issue is the values of the sizes are not displayed in the table since there is a slash ("/") in the property name and it considers the property name as a different path.

The problem is, cannot remove the slash from the property name. is there any workaround for that to display property values with a slash ("/") in the property name.

Comment: what about a formatter, that replaces the / with the escaped form of it?

Comment: Cannot replace it since need to display the exact value as the column name

Comment: First question: Are you trying to bind in the xml view?

If not then in controller you can you do something like this below:

Just use myObject["key"] instead of myObject.key:

example: alert(myObject["S/4"]);

You cannot use / because it is another operator. If you have / or . in your field names, it is wise to use the [] operator.

Comment: Here I'm creating a table from javascript and define column templates and set the model as datasource

Comment: @tarzanbappa did you come up with a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: @sonja still no. but can do a workaround by having a separate column for binding without the forward-slash and original one as the column name. When you saving the records need to set the values in the entities by checking the correct properties of the entity

Comment: Are the property names coming from an OData service e.g. `<Property Name="XL/6" Type="Edm...." />` in $metadata?